# My prefix is a god, better known as arthritis

Tags: riddle, word, word-property

Take away half of me, I become unnatural

But give me your honey, I'll become an animal

I may ruin your day

But I'll always be followed by a ray

... And my prefix is a god... although Google thinks he's Arthritis.

---

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are:

> RAIN

Take away half of me, I become unnatural

> Removing half the letters yields "AI", or Artificial Intelligence.

But give me your honey, I'll become an animal

> Add a B (bee, which makes honey), and get "BRAIN". Animals have brains.

I may ruin your day

> Bad weather is associated with ruining a sunny day.

But I'll always be followed by a ray

> Rain is followed by a rainbow.

... And my prefix is a god... although Google thinks he's Arthritis.

> Begins with "RA", which can be an Egyptian deity. The top Google result for "RA" is Rheumatoid Arthritis.

Comment: The animal bit seems a bit of a stretch? Not doubting that it's the intended answer, but there's nothing about it that particularly suggests animal?

Comment: @Mohirl, I was actually going for Reindeer, but his explanation works as well.